# how to check admin config before overriding a block?

Tags: magento2

i have custom module

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sample_Menus" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

after i
Creating di.xml to refer the overriding block class

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Sample\Menus\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

so how to check if in config is Enable then overriding block `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` else is disable not overriding?

**I tried**

```
 protected function _toHtml()
    {       
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu'));
        // check Mageaddons_Menus is acitve
        if($this->getActive() === '1'){
            $this->setTemplate('Sample_Menus::html/topmenu.phtml');
        }       
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Check if enabled
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActive() {
      return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('menus/menus/enabled', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
```

but when set config not endable. it not render teample of `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`
any idea can help. thanks

Comment: your are looking validation from `.php` file or `.xml` file?

Comment: Use a constructor to check in your custom block and return parent if not enabled

Comment: sr . i edited question.